# Django returns NoReverseMatch instead of Updating the div with Ajax

Tags: django, ajax, url

## Description

I am creating a like button for a comment that was made on a post.

When the user clicks on the like button, Django gives a **NoReverseMatch** and the page doesn't update automatically.

After I refresh the page, it shows that the like was updated in the database, despite the **NoReverseMatch** error.

## What I tried?

Initially, the issue was with the csrf_tokens. So, I added the csrf_exempt decorator, so it is definitely not the issue.

I played a lot with the urls, and tried adding the comment id to the parameter, but it doesn't seem to help.

## Question

How can I resolve the NoReverseMatch error and make it so that AJAX automatically changes the button from like to dislike.

**urls.py**

```
path('post/<int:pk>/like-comment', like_comment, name="like_comment")
```

**view.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def like_comment(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    liked = False
    if comment.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        comment.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        comment.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True

    context = {
       'comment': comment,
       'is_liked': liked,
       'total_likes': comment.likes.count()
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/like_section_comment.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
  $(document).on('click', '#like-comment', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var pk1 = $(this).attr('value'); // comment id
    var pk = $(this).attr('data-value'); // post id
    

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "like-comment",
      data: {'id': pk1, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
      dataType: 'json',


      success: function(response) {
         $('#like-section-comment').html(response['form'])
         console.log($('#like-section-comment').html(response['form']));
      },


      error: function(rs, e) {
         console.log(rs.responseText);
      },

   });
 });
});
```

**comment_section.html**

```
<article class="media content-section">
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form id="like-form-comment" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if request.user in comment.likes.all %}
            <button type="submit" id="like-comment" name="comment_id" data-value="{{ comment.post.id }}" value="{{ comment.id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                Dislike
            </button>
        {% else %}
            <button type="submit" id="like-comment" name="comment_id" data-value="{{ comment.post.id }}" value="{{ comment.id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                Like
            </button>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat the URL endpoint related to this request is at the top!

Answer (score 1):

You write `url: "like-comment",` how would that map to the correct url? Javascript does not know anything about Django. Try this instead:
In your html:

```
<button type="submit" id="like-comment" name="comment_id" data-value="{{ comment.post.id }}" value="{{ comment.id }}" data-submit-url="{% url 'like_comment' comment.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
```

Now in your JavaScript:

```
url: $(this).attr('data-submit-url'),
```

Comment: NoReverseMatch
       at /post/30/like-comment
  Reverse for &#x27;post-detail&#x27; with arguments &#x27;(&#x27;&#x27;,)&#x27; not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [&#x27;post/(?P&lt;pk&gt;[0-9]+)/$&#x27;]

Comment: @David that is likely an error in your template `like_section_comment.html`....